# How to separate a python class that needs access the kv file

Tags: python, class, import, kivy, ids

So I have a class in my python file that I want to seperate from the main python file because I will need to modify it a couple time and use it in the main one. However since the class needs access to the kivy file to read the ids I cannot seperate this class from the main one without loading the kv file twice which messes everything up. How can I basically make this class importable?

```py
class RightSide(BoxLayout):
    order_size = []
    overlay = StringProperty('Current Order will be displayed here')
    tabname = parameter_length
    iterator = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'

        for i in range(len(menu)):
            self.add_widget(Skeleton())

    def tally(self):
        global OID
        order_size = self.order_size
        print(OID)
        OID = OID + 1
        print(OID)
        rightside = kv.ids.one.two.three.newlay.rightside
        for skel in rightside.children:
            if isinstance(skel, Skeleton):
                if self.iterator > len(menu)-1:
                    self.iterator = 0
                    order_size.clear()

                self.tabname[self.iterator] = skel.drink_name, skel.ids.label_id.text
                self.iterator = self.iterator + 1
                order_size.insert(0, skel.ids.label_id.text)

        order_size.insert(0, OID)

        self.tabname.reverse()
        self.tabname.insert(0, OID)

        makeitastring = ''.join(map(str, self.tabname))
        self.overlay = makeitastring
        con = sql.connect(host='xxxxxx', user='root', password='xxxxxxx.', database='new_schema')
        cur = con.cursor()




        cur.execute(query, order_size)



        con.commit()
        con.close()



    def clean(self):
        rightside = kv.ids.one.two.three.newlay.rightside
        for skel in rightside.children:
            if isinstance(skel, Skeleton):
                skel.ids.label_id.text = '0'
                skel.count = 0




kv = Builder.load_file("b.kv")
```

Comment: Access to `ids` has no relationship to what file a class is defined in.

Comment: however the kv needs to be define in order for me to iterate through the ids, if I dont define the kv in the py file this class is in it gives an error since the kv doesnt equal to anything

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to declare the kv variable in a seperate py file using "import new_file.py" and accessing it via "new_file.kv"

Comment: Assuming that somewhere in your code you have an `App` that returns `kv` from its `build()` method, then you can access `kv` as `App.get_runnng_app().root` from anywhere in your code.